# Remove spacing between menu bar and picture

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm new to website coding, how do I remove this spacing (circled in red) from my website? I'm using the free edition so I can't add custom css.

[image]

**My code is below:**

```
<!-- wp:group {"align":"full","style":{"spacing":{"margin":{"top":"0px","bottom":"0px"}}},"layout":{"type":"constrained","contentSize":"100%!important"}}
   --> 
<div class="wp-block-group alignfull" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px">
<!-- wp:navigation {"ref":56,"textColor":"background","customBackgroundColor":"#946F50","layout":{"type":"default","contentSize":"100%","justifyContent":"center","flexWrap":"nowrap"}} /-->
<!-- wp:columns --> 
<div class="wp-block-columns alignfull">
<!-- wp:column {"width":"66.5%","style":{"spacing":{"padding":{"right":"0px","left":"0px"}}},"layout":{"type":"default"}}
   --> 
<div class="wp-block-column" style="padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;flex-basis:66.5%">
   <!-- wp:image {"id":69,"sizeSlug":"full","linkDestination":"none"} --> 
   <figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img src="https://zhiiweii.files.wordpress.com/2024/03/pexels-pixabay-257894.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-69" /></figure>
   <!-- /wp:image -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:column -->
```

I can't find a solution